# Converting data encoding with lapply crashes Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a Shiny app and am converting the encodings of my data via iconv with the following lines.

`` df$`Column 1`<- iconv(df$`Column 1`, to = "UTF-8") ``

`` df$`Column 2`<- iconv(df$`Column 2`, to = "UTF-8") ``

This works fine, but seen as there are multiple columns, this is obviously not a tidy solution. I'm trying to employ `lapply` to apply the same logic to all my columns, however this crashes my app with no errors, warnings or traceback.

`df<- lapply(df, iconv, to = "UTF-8")`

Could anybody shed some light on why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

`df[1:ncol(df)] <- lapply(df[1:ncol(df)], iconv, to = "UTF-8")`

This workaround gave me the solution I needed. I'm not entirely sure why.